# Tight bounds on $\binom{n_1}{2}+\binom{n_2}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n_k}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

Let $n ~(\ge 8)$ be an integer and $n=n_1+n_2+\cdots +n_k$ where every $n_i$ is an positive integer and $2 \le k <n$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $n_1 \ge n_2 \ge \cdots \ge n_k.$

Are there exact expressions for the upper and lower bounds of the following expression?

$$f(n_1,n_2,\cdots n_k):=\binom{n_1}{2}+\binom{n_2}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n_k}{2}$$

Note that $\binom{1}{2}=0$.

I did some calculations for some special cases.

For $n=8$ and $k=2$, we have

$$\max f=f(7,1)=21$$
and
$$\min f=f(4,4)=12.$$

Now if $k=3$, then we have

$$\max f=f(6,1,1)=15$$
and
$$\min f=f(3,2,2)=7.$$

It seems that we have

$$\max f:=f(\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil,\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor)$$
and
$$\min f:=f(2,\underbrace{1,1,1\dots,1}_{n-2}).$$

Comment: This seems like it would follow from convexity of ${x\choose 2}:=x(x-1)/2$.

Comment: I believe what you're saying is going in the right direction. But I haven't thought of any proof yet.

Comment: I'd start with a proof that ${x+y\choose 2}>{x\choose 2}+{y\choose 2}$.

Comment: is $k$ fixed or variable ?

Comment: @dezdichado I didn't make it clear.  I consider both cases you mentioned. First, $k$ is fixed.  Further we can consider that $k$ can be variable.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers gets the exact answer for the minimum when $k$ divides $n$, which is when all the $n_i$ are equal to $\frac{n}{k}$ and so the value at the minimum of $f$ is $\frac{n^2}{2k}-\frac{n}{2}$ in this case.